# xdg-open opens my .desktop file in text viewer or editor instead of launching the executable I want

Tags: xdg, desktop-shortcuts

I tried to create a .desktop file to launch xfreerdp with certain command-line arguments, using https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries as a quick reference. Its file name is `something.desktop` and its text contents is like that :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=RemoteApp
Terminal=true
Exec="/usr/bin/xfreerdp /d:somedomain /v:somehost /app:'||'AppAlias /from-stdin /timeout:60000"
```

And, I am unable to launch it with `xdg-open`. Under Kubuntu 21.04 `xdg-open` uses `kde-open5` which opens its text in Okular. Under Linux Mint Mate 19.3 it uses `gio open` which opens it in xed editor. But what I actually wanted is to open a terminal, under which to run xfreerdp. Adding `Version=1.0` surely does not help. Adding executable bits with `chmod` - neither. Trying to open this launcher from KDE's Dolphin gives me error 100, could not find command "the whole line in quotes". I feel I have got into some fundamental misconception, and I hope someone wise and experienced could help me overcome it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try `dex something.desktop` (apt install dex).

Comment: dex apparently does the job, but what I want to be able in the end, is to distribute this .desktop file and have it runnable by other users under their presumedly xdg-compliant desktop environments and/or file managers. Are there ways to achieve this without involving dex ?

Comment: Sounds like the mimetype changed for .desktop files. Search for `mimeapps.list` and see if there are any references to xed.